# Count displayed lines in textarea using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, textarea

When I say line, I mean wrapped line as displayed in the textarea. A long line will wrap to multiple lines. If a line (ending with newline) wraps into three lines, the count has to be three.

The problem is that line breaks happen not just at spaces but also at other character sequences. For example in Firefox, `aaaaaa*<bbbbbb` will break after `*` if there's not enough space in the same line.

What this means is that we can't simply use the number of characters that can fit in the textarea's width and spaces to figure out the number of displayed lines. Obviously, counting newlines is not useful since it ignores wrapping. There's a way to force newline insertion at line breaks by using the textarea attribute `wrap="hard"`. As I understand, this happens only when the form is submitted to server. This is not a suitable solution since we wish to do counting in JavaScript.

Another variant of the problem question is, "Is there a way to move the cursor to next displayed line?" I tried the following but this doesn't move the cursor at all, it only "mimics" down arrow key event:

```
var e = $.Event( "keydown", { which: 40 } );
...
$(this).trigger(e);
```